# Custom editor with split core editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, editor, designer, vsix

I need to create a custom designer with a split view. The first half of the view would be the code, the second would be a designer/preview for previewing some custom HTML code. Just like XAML designer.

I already have a Window Tool implemented, but now I want it integrated inside the editor so that it would show only for certain file types.

My best guess is that I would need to create a [Custom Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-editors-and-designers), but I don't know how to get The Visual Studio core editor control to include it? If that's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something very easy and fast to implement without implementing a  VSPackage, I believe you can do it with a WPF application, where you have a multiline TextBox (editor) and a WebBrowser control (preview)

When text changes into the editor you can check Html syntax (e.g. you can check if you can deserialize). If the syntax is correct you call [NavigateToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
_webBrowser.NavigateToString(_editor.Text);
```

If you **must** develop a VSPackage, forget my answer.

Comment: I already have everything what you are saying implemented using CEF browser, Node.JS in the background, etc.. as a VSPackage. But not as an editor, but as a Tool Window. Now I want it to be integrated with the actual Visual Studio core editor side by side, just like XAML.